# libmpich.so.10 missing

Tags: software-installation, shared-library

Yesterday I wanted to launch one of my older programs to generate some matrices. The problem is, it didn't work. I got this error:

```
./matrixBinaryGenerator: error while loading shared libraries: libmpich.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to reinstall `mpich`, `mpich2` and `libmpich-dev`, but even if all of them have reinstalled succesfully, it didn't solve my problem.

So, I know, that this is a pretty beginners' question, but, do you know how could I install this library? I prefer not to install it manually (from RPM etc.), but from some repository.

---

My program uses PETSC, my OS is Ubuntu 14.10.

---

This is the version of my MPI:

```
HYDRA build details:
    Version:                                 3.1
    Release Date:                            Thu Feb 20 11:41:13 CST 2014
    CC:                              gcc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    CXX:                             g++ -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    F77:                             gfortran -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    F90:                             gfortran -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro 
    Configure options:                       '--disable-option-checking' '--prefix=/usr' '--build=x86_64-linux-gnu' '--includedir=${prefix}/include' '--mandir=${prefix}/share/man' '--infodir=${prefix}/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--localstatedir=/var' '--libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--disable-maintainer-mode' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--enable-shared' '--enable-fc' '--disable-rpath' '--disable-wrapper-rpath' '--sysconfdir=/etc/mpich' '--libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' '--includedir=/usr/include/mpich' '--docdir=/usr/share/doc/mpich' '--with-hwloc-prefix=system' '--enable-checkpointing' '--with-hydra-ckpointlib=blcr' 'build_alias=x86_64-linux-gnu' 'MPICHLIB_CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'MPICHLIB_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'MPICHLIB_FFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4' 'MPICHLIB_FCFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4' 'CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro ' 'CPPFLAGS=-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -I/build/buildd/mpich-3.1/src/mpl/include -I/build/buildd/mpich-3.1/src/mpl/include -I/build/buildd/mpich-3.1/src/openpa/src -I/build/buildd/mpich-3.1/src/openpa/src -I/build/buildd/mpich-3.1/src/mpi/romio/include' 'CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security' 'F77=gfortran' 'FFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -O2' 'FC=gfortran' 'FCFLAGS=-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4' '--cache-file=/dev/null' '--srcdir=.' 'CC=gcc' 'LIBS=-lrt -lcr -lpthread '
    Process Manager:                         pmi
    Launchers available:                     ssh rsh fork slurm ll lsf sge manual persist
    Topology libraries available:            hwloc
    Resource management kernels available:   user slurm ll lsf sge pbs cobalt
    Checkpointing libraries available:       blcr
    Demux engines available:                 poll select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've found a workaround for this. I found out, that instead of `libmpich.so.10` there is `libmpich.so.12` on my system. So I created a symlink and it works :-)

---

#### Command:

```
ln -s libmpich.so.10 libmpich.so.12
```